# What is advantage of Hyper-Q of GK110 over Concurrent Kernels of GK104/GF104 nvidia cards?

Tags: cuda

If I have multithread application and my own thread that control CUDA device and schedule kernels to different streams I can achieve very high GPU usage also on devices prior to Kepler-2 (GK110) famaly like Fermi and Kepler-1 (GK104).

So I don't see good reason aspire to more expensive cards.

flowing my test example and profiling on Fermi card:

```
void ut_concurent_kernels()
{
  int i,j;
  cudaEvent_t kernelEvent;
  cudaStream_t    work_stream[14];


  for (i = 0; i < 14;i++)
  {
    cudaStreamCreate( &work_stream[i]);
  }
  cudaEventCreateWithFlags(&kernelEvent, cudaEventDisableTiming);

  for (j = 0; j < 2;j++)
  {
    for (i = 0; i < 14;i++)
    {
      if (i == 13)
      {
        checkCudaErrors(cudaEventRecord(kernelEvent, work_stream[i]));
      }
      Kernel_Work<<<1,256,0,work_stream[i]>>>(100000);
    }
    checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamWaitEvent(work_stream[i-1], kernelEvent,0));
  }
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  for (i = 0; i < 14;i++)
  {
    cudaStreamDestroy(work_stream[i]);
  }
  cudaEventDestroy(kernelEvent);
}
```

[image: Profiling]

Answer (score 2):

I believe the most programmer-visible manifestation of Hyper-Q is a linux feature called CUDA Multi-Process-Server (MPS).  The principal use-case for CUDA MPS (on top of Hyper-Q) at this time is to enable MPI cluster compute jobs to share GPUs amongst several MPI ranks, for MPI ranks executing on the same node, as discussed [here](http://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/2012/08/23/unleash-legacy-mpi-codes-with-keplers-hyper-q/).  In this case, multiple MPI ranks normally operate out of independent CPU *processes* (as opposed to threads) and CUDA MPS/Hyper-Q provides a convenient sharing mechanism.

As already noted, Hyper-Q is a hardware feature that is available in cc3.5 devices, but not in cc 1.x - 3.0 devices.   In the context of a single application process, whether single- or multi-threaded, I know of no advantages or compelling use cases that CUDA MPS(on top of Hyper-Q) provides over managing multiple concurrent execution yourself.

With respect to managing multiple concurrent execution yourself, Hyper-Q will (transparently) provide benefits to the programmer as described by @Greg Smith in his comments below.  There are no specific requirements to take advantage of it in a cc3.5 device, and conceptually, the user will manage concurrent execution using the same overall methodology, but may experience improved concurrency, or the ability to achieve improved concurrency, in a cc3.5 device, due to the hardware advances in Hyper-Q.  As Greg suggests and OP has demonstrated, it is still possible to achieve concurrency in pre-cc3.5 devices, but the opportunities to do so may be more limited, or may require less than obvious programming techniques.  To get a more detailed view of these issues, refer to slides 15-22 [here](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf)

Comment: Hyper-Q in a single application allows for up to 32 independent streams of commands to the device. This differs from previous CC2.* and 3.0 devices that only have a single communication channel to the device. CC2.0-3.0 devices can execute kernels concurrently but there is a high likelihood of false dependencies and serialization due to the communication channel. This often requires developers to submit launches and memory copies in unnatural ways to avoid these false dependencies.